# How to click the save button in form automatically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an form with dropdown. whenever i select the drop down once i click save itself it appear it do some action. I want to as auto save when you change the dropdown values.
Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GGtTw/

```
jQuery('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() { 
alert(jQuery(this).val());
});
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    alert('you click submit button');
});
```

I want once you select the dropdown it automatically submit the values means it automatically click save without noticing to the user.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to simulate a click event for the given object

```
jQuery('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() { 
    jQuery('#submit').trigger('click');
});
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    alert('you click submit button');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
$( "#submit" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Approach:

```
jQuery('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() { 
    save();
});
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    save();
});
function save()
{
alert('Save');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an ajax call to save from inside your drop down change event. Unless you want to perform a form submit, in that case trigger the click function on the submit like so

```
jQuery('#submit').trigger('click');
```

[jQuery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Technically correct, but strikes me as an unnecessarily large amount of work for such a trivial problem.

Comment: Anthony, typically on a drop down select, there is no need for a post back, so an ajax save call is usually what people do.